# Dropdown menu with onClick

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, state, html-select

I'm trying to create a dropdown menu with 3 options.
Once an option is selected, it triggers an change in a state. I tried a few different ways but they don't work.

This is the first attempt:

```
<div className='dropDownDiv'>
  <select>  
    <button onClick={()=> setResultsPerPage(6)}>6 Results</button>
    <button onClick={()=> setResultsPerPage(9)}>9 Results</button>
    <button onClick={()=> setResultsPerPage(15)}>Max sites</button>
  </select>
</div>
```

Then I tried this:

```
<div className='dropDownDiv'>
  <select>  
    <option onClick={()=> setResultsPerPage(6)}>6 Results</option>
    <option onClick={()=> setResultsPerPage(9)}>9 Results</option>
    <option onClick={()=> setResultsPerPage(15)}>Max sites</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

The second attempt shows the options in the dropdown but still doesn't trigger the onClick. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For [select tags](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#the-select-tag), you want to add a [`change` event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) on the parent *`select`* element rather than the individual `option` elements.

The `option` elements should have a `value`, which is then read in the `onChange` handler from the event's [target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target).

```js
function Form() {
    const [resultsPerPage, setResultsPerPage] = React.useState(6);

    return (
        <div>
            <select value={resultsPerPage} onChange={(event) => setResultsPerPage(event.target.value)}>
                <option value={6}>6 Results</option>
                <option value={9}>9 Results</option>
                <option value={15}>Max sites</option>
            </select>
            <p>Results per page: {resultsPerPage}</p>
        </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Form />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```